# Plotting Graph of Zeno paradoxes

Tags: plotting, programming, homework

Zeno Paradoxes is about a Greek Heroes Archilles having a race with tortoise. the tortoise given a head start `distance`. Greek heroes Archilles have constant speed of `VelocityArchilles`. while tortoise have speed of `VelocityTortoise`. but Archilles have some problem. when Archilles reach the head start of the tortoise, new gap is create by tortoise and it is going on and on. How do i plot the graph of `"Distance between Archilles and tortoise as a function of time"`, `"Distance of Archilles and tortoise as a function of n"` and `"time elapsed as function of n"`

this is my code so far and i use syntax `Do[]`

```
distance = 1000.0; (*the distance in meter*)
VelocityTortoise = 10.0^-3; (*velocity turtle in m/s*)
VelocityArchilles = 10.0; (*velocity Archilles in m/s*)
time = 0.0; (*initial time*)
nlastzeno = 30.0;
Do[time = distance/(VelocityArchilles);
 distance = (VelocityTortoise)*(time);
 Print["at run ", n, 
  " the distance between the greek god and tortoise is", distance, 
  " meter. with time difference ", time, " sec"];

 (*If[distance<10.0^-10,run=n;Print["The Greek God succeded catch up \
with the tortoise at run ",n,"."];Break[]]*), {n, 1, nlastzeno, 1}]
```

[image: zeno paradoxes diagram]

Comment: You can format inline code and code blocks by selecting the code and clicking the `{}` button above the edit window. The edit window help button `?` is also useful for learning how to format your questions and answers. You may also find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: If you were told to use **Do[ ]**, go find another professor. The one you're having doesn't know Mathematica - at all

Comment: Take a look [here](http://demonstrations.wolfram.com/ZenosParadoxAchillesAndTheTortoise/) as well.

Comment: AFAIK Αχιλλέας was revered as a hero, not as a god

Comment: @Dr.belisarius have some respect for professors! He's just secretly trying to keep the ancient language of BASIC alive.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You'll learn more trying to understand the following code than by programming silly `Do[ ]s`

```
startA = 0;
startT = 1000;
velA = 10;
velT = 9;
pos[start_, vel_, time_] := start + vel time
tf = t /. First@Solve[pos[startA, velA, t] == pos[startT, velT, t]];

Plot[{pos[startA, velA, t], pos[startT, velT, t]}, {t, 0, tf}, 
     AxesLabel -> {Time, Position}, 
     PlotLabel -> ("Catch up time = " <> ToString@N@tf)]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
f = FindSequenceFunction@NestList[
     (Solve[pos[startA, velA, t2] == pos[startT, velT, #]][[1, 1, 2]]) &, 0, 10];

ListLinePlot[f /@ Range[100], 
             PlotLabel -> "Time Elapsed as a function of n", PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[
 Table[pos[startT, velT, #] - pos[startA, velA, #] &@f[n], {n, 1, 100}], 
            PlotLabel -> "Distance as a function of n", 
            PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

```
ListLinePlot[
 Transpose@Table[{pos[startT, velT, #], pos[startA, velA, #]} &@f[n], {n, 1,  50}], 
            PlotLabel -> "Position of both heroes as a function of n", 
            PlotRange -> All]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]